# Modeling the minimum number of moves in the Tower of Hanoi problem. [Concrete Mathematics Textbook]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I read the other related question but it doesn't quite answer my question.

"If T<sub>n</sub> is the minimum number of moves for the Tower of Hanoi problem

T<sub>0</sub> + 1 = 1;

T<sub>n</sub> + 1 = 2T<sub>n-1</sub>

Now if we let U<sub>n</sub> = T<sub>n</sub> + 1 for n  > 0

U<sub>0</sub> = 1;

U<sub>n</sub> = 2U<sub>n - 1</sub>

It doesn't take a genius to discover that the solution to this recurrence is just U<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> "

I guess I'm not a genius because I don't understand that logical leap from 2U<sub>n-1</sub> to  2<sup>n</sup>.

Comment: What is the step you don't get? Is it going from $T_n$ to $U_n$, or is it concluding that $U_n=2^n$ from the given recurrence?

Comment: Concluding that U<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> from the recurrence

Comment: @Joshua: $U_0=1=2^0$. Each time you increase the subscript by $1$, you double the value of $U_n$, and each time you increase the exponent by $1$, $2^n$ doubles. Thus, $U_n$ and $2^n$ are equal when $n=0$ and grow in exactly the same way as $n$ increases, so they must always be the same. (For practice you should recast this informal explanation as a proof by induction that $U_n=2^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.)